# The VF page is in a pop up window. When the Case is created I want the parent window to redirect to the newly created Case

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Have a link that calls a VF page for a user to fill in  required fields then create a Test Record.
The VF page is in a pop up window.

When the Test__C is created I want the parent window to redirect to the newly created Record.

Everything works except closing the pop-up and redirecting the parent window.

Comment: Just a thought, I typically avoid using popups.  Users typically don't like them and managing the interaction between windows is a pain.  Why not just have the link open in the current window?

Comment: This is a My client requirement. Thats why we are using this. Please suggest me.

Comment: is the parent a detail page or another vfpage

Comment: This could be of help http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/forums/forumtopicprintpage/board-id/Visualforce/message-id/45288/print-single-message/false/page/1

Comment: Its another visualforce page but it having view of that record

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not using a popup at all, instead use a modal popup which basically is a outputpanel in the parent VF page which is rendered as and when you  want to show it.

You could very easily call any page using the page reference method.
With this solution you dont need to worry about popup blockers blocking popups.

A detailed explanation of the code can be found in http://www.tehnrd.com/visualforce-pop-up/

Comment: That is ok for show and  hide. But my case is different. When the Test__C is created I want the parent window to redirect to the newly created Record. Right now it is redirecting to direct to another page but i want to redirect to the newly created Record.

Answer (score 0):

In your VF page controller method when your record is created successfully then you cna add below code for redirecting it to newly created record :

```
PageReference ref = new PageReference('/'+ test__c.Id);
ref.setRedirect(true);
return ref;
```

And before that onclick of the save button you can call one javascript line :

```
window.close();
```

After this call controller method and use the PageReference code whioch will redirect you to the newly created record screen.